# Rails - How to use hidden field on form to pass a value of an object related to the one created on a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to pass an `rfid_tag` from a form that creates a `device` from a `hidden_field`.  Device `has_many rfids`.  The `rfid` already exists in the db.

Here is the code from the form:

```
<th>RFID Tag #</th>
<td>
  <%= f.label(:@passed_rfid_tag, @passed_rfid_tag) %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :rfid_tag, :value => @passed_rfid_tag %>
</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the code from the devices_controller:

```
def create
   @cabinet = Cabinet.find(params[:device][:cabinet_id])
   @device = Device.create(params[:device])
   @device.rfids << Rfid.where('rfid_tag' => params[:rfid_tag]).first
   @device.row_id = @cabinet.row_id
   @device.save
```

I get the following error because `rfid_tag` is not an attribute of `device`.  It is an attribute of `rfid`:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: rfid_tag

app/controllers/devices_controller.rb:182:in `create'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mass-assign error is happening because you are passing `:rfid_tag` as part of the `params[:device]` attribute hash.

In your example code, the `:rfid_tag` field needs to be provided using the `hidden_field_tag` form helper. This will keep it from being included in the `params[:device]` hash.

```
<tr>
  <th>RFID Tag #</th>
  <td>
    <%= label_tag 'rfid_tag', 'RFID Tag' %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'rfid_tag', @passed_rfid_tag %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

You can then access it via `params[:rfid_tag]`. Your `create` method should still work.

Comment: `The mass-assign error is happening because you are passing :rfid_tag as part of the params[:device] attribute hash.`
Dan, i have just checked this and this is not true. I passed extra params in my create actions and everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Do what Dan Reedy said and use a hidden_field_tag in your form.

I'm concerned about this line in your controller's create method:

```
@device.rfids << Rfid.where('rfid_tag' => params[:rfid_tag]).first
```

That's good if your rfid also has many devices, so you have a many to many relationship. If an rfid tag goes with exactly one device though you'll probably need to change that to something like:

```
rfid = Rfid.where('rfid_tag' => params[:rfid_tag]).first
rfid.device_id = @device.id
rfid.save!
```

And of course be sure to handle the cases where the cabinet_id or the rfid_tag you get from the params hash are not found in the database. Can't ever count on user provided input to be valid or correspond to real records, even if it's from hidden fields.